# Python csv.writer adds unwanted characters

Tags: python, csv, writer

I am letting my script read a csv file and I want to save it first into an array, then slice the second element (which is the second line of my csv file) and write the array back to the csv file. csv file looks like this before:

```
first name,username,age,status
test1,test1_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test2,test2_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test3,test3_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test4,test4_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test5,test5_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test6,test6_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test7,test7_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test8,test8_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
```

After running my script, the csv is this:

```
first name,username,age,status
test2', 'test2_username', '28', '2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00']]
test3', 'test3_username', '28', '2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00']]
test4', 'test4_username', '28', '2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00']]
test5', 'test5_username', '28', '2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00']]
test6', 'test6_username', '28', '2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00']]
test7', 'test7_username', '28', '2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00']]
test8', 'test8_username', '28', '2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00']]
```

But this is the output which I want (The same as before but without the second line):

```
first name,username,age,status
test2,test2_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test3,test3_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test4,test4_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test5,test5_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test6,test6_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test7,test7_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test8,test8_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
```

If I run it multiple times then more characters like ' and " are appearing out of nowhere? Why does this happen?

How exactly do I solve this problem? This is my code:

```py
data = []

rows = []
with open('list.csv', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    for row in data:
        rows.append([row,])

rows = rows[2:]
with open('list.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as g:
    writer = csv.writer(g, delimiter="\n")
    writer2 = csv.writer(g, lineterminator="\n")
    writer2.writerow(['first name', 'username', 'age', 'status'])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you wrapping the row in another list with `[row,]`? It's already a list.

Comment: Just do `rows.append(row)`. Or you can avoid the loop entirely with `rows = list(data)`

Comment: Why do you create two `csv.writer()` instances writing to the same file? And where is the code that writes `rows` to the file?

Comment: This problem doesn't even need the CSV module.  You just want to copy a text file while deleting the second line.  That's only a few lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not writing anything to the output file (or it is missing in example). Also, use `writer.writerows` to write the data:

```py
import csv

rows = []
with open("in.csv", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",", lineterminator="\n")
    for row in data:
        rows.append(row)    # <-- append only `row` to the list, not `[row]`

rows = rows[2:]
with open("out.csv", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as g:
    writer = csv.writer(g, lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerow(["first name", "username", "age", "status"])
    writer.writerows(rows)  # <-- use `writer.writerows` to write the data in one one step
```

`out.csv` will contain:

```
first name,username,age,status
test2,test2_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test3,test3_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test4,test4_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test5,test5_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test6,test6_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test7,test7_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
test8,test8_username,28,2023-08-18 13:41:10+00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the brackets and quotes because you're wrapping each row in another list. Rows should be 1-dimensional lists, not 2-dimensional.

If you want to remove a row from the CSV, you can simplify it by just deleting that element from `rows`, then writing all the rows back to the file.

```
with open('list.csv', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    rows = list(csv.reader(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n"))

del rows[1]

with open('list.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as g:
    csv.writer(g,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n").writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score -1):

Less lines with pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('in.csv')
df = df.drop([0]) #drop row
out = df.to_csv('out.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: Yes, but pandas is HUGE.  It hardly seems necessary to drag in all of that for this simple task.  Even the CSV is not necessary here.